# What's causing this error? "Warning: Invalid argument"

Tags: plugins, admin, errors, admin-menu, core

I noticed today that my error logs are littered with this information. I'm not quite sure what's causing it. Has anyone seen this before?

`[Mon Mar 25 17:24:23 2013] [error] [client] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/mysite/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php on line 1290, referer: http://mysite/contact/`

Line `1290` is the `foreach` in the following code. I am not sure what's referencing this or where to begin looking.

```
/**
 * Remove a top level admin menu
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param string $menu_slug The slug of the menu
 * @return array|bool The removed menu on success, False if not found
 */

function remove_menu_page( $menu_slug ) {
global $menu;

foreach ( $menu as $i => $item ) {
    if ( $menu_slug == $item[2] ) {
        unset( $menu[$i] );
        return $item;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

I'm not hooking into `admin_menu` as far as I can tell.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is most likely caused by a plugin. Deactivate them all, and reactivate one by one.

Comment: Looks like I narrowed it down to a plugin, which tells me I must have been getting this error for a few months and just didn't notice. Pop that one liner into an answer and I'll check it off for you. Thanks @vancoder

Comment: Was it a Twitter (or twitter related) plugin perchance? they've recently updated their API so a lot of plugins are failing.

Comment: No it was WP Most Popular (which for what it's worth, never seemed to work rock-solid anyways). http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-most-popular/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by a plugin. Deactivate them all, and reactivate one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while developing my own plugin. Turns out that I didn't [uninstall menu the right way](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/administration-menus/top-level-menus/#remove-a-top-level-menu) in uninstall.php. Here is right way with hook:

```
function myplugin_remove_menus() {
remove_menu_page( 'myplugin-admin-menu' );
remove_menu_page( 'myplugin-admin-menu-logs' );
}
// proper way with admin_menu hook
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin_remove_menus' );
```